# Unicode strings being stored in MySQL database

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

My application uses Zope 2.12.19.
Python 2.6.8.
MySQL 5.5

1. Unicode Support is enabled in Zope using the ZMySQLDA connector.
2. sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8') is set in the sitecustomize.py file of python.
3. All the 'character_set%' and 'collation%' variables in MySQL have been changed to use utf-8.

The application copes well with all characters as long as they are entered from the browser.
But when I execute a Python script that reads from the database and later writes to the database, the tables contain Unicode strings. For ex... u'stack' instead of just stack.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening ?

Comment: Please show us the code that doesn't work.

Comment: `customers = context.SQL.selectCustomers().dictionaries()
context.LOG.DEBUG('customers',customers)`                                                   This fetches and inserts into the database table, the customer records.    DEBUG is an sql file that inserts data into a table (customers is the data in this case).

Comment: I think that the ZMySQLDA is not encoding the Unicode string using utf8 before writing it to the database. Is this a bug in ZMySQLDA ? As I have said, instead of manually running a script, if a form is submitted from the application, the data is correctly encoded and stored in the database. This problem seems to happen only when a Python script reads data from the database. Testing this script using Zope Management Interface shows the unicode strings. What does this mean ? Python not encoding the results received from Mysql query ?

Comment: Could you [edit] the post to add details?

Comment: I suspect you are receiving unicode but the ZMySQLDA adapter or page template is not encoding it to UTF-8 but to `repr()` representations somewhere. Z SQL methods are old tech and not really supported anymore.

Comment: So what do you suggest ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20662/discussion-between-ravi-and-martijn-pieters)

Comment: Is it normal that when you insert a list in the database, that they contain unicode strings. Ex: [u'Hello',u'World']. As I have stated above, these tables that have lists stored are used for debugging purposes.